# How to uninstall freefilesync from Ubuntu

Tags: software-center, uninstall, software-uninstall

I installed FreeFileSync for my Ubuntu 20.04 from here;
https://freefilesync.org/download.php

Installation was successful and the app is working. The problem is I can't remove FreeFileSync from my device.

1. I tried ubuntu software centre: It is not listed there
2. Tried following commands. But none did work

```
sudo apt remove freefilesync
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package freefilesync
```

```
sudo apt-get autoremove freefilesync
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package freefilesync
```

Any help?

**Update:**
Here is the output for `which freefilesync`

```
aca@aca-00:~$ which FreeFileSync
aca@aca-00:~$ which freefilesync
aca@aca-00:~$ which RealtimeFileSync
aca@aca-00:~$
```

No output actually :(

**Update 2; My ubuntu Version**

Output of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

**Update 3: Problem Solved**

There is an uninstall.sh file at `/opt/FreeFileSync/`.

Comment: Please add output of `which FreeFileSync` to the question. You have probably downloaded tar-ball and extracted it to somewhere.

Comment: @guiverc I updated the question with version details. And I am sorry about that, I am just a noob. I was simply trying different commands I found on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed FreeFileSync with the FreeFileSync_11.21_Install.run file that you extracted from FreeFileSync_11.21_Linux.tar.gz that you downloaded from https://freefilesync.org/download.php, run the uninstall.sh file located at /opt/FreeFileSync.

Answer (score 0):

Previously FreeFileSync was available as tarball, so one should download it, extract to somewhere and then adjust `$PATH` variable in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and put desktop-file into `~/.local/share/applications`.
You have to check `which FreeFileSync` and `which RealtimeFileSync` and decide is it your case or not.

Currently FreeFileSync is [shipped as FlatPak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.freefilesync.FreeFileSync), to remove it use command below:

```
flatpak remove org.freefilesync.FreeFileSync
```

Comment: Nothing works :( . I can't locate my app at `~/.local/share/applications`. Flatpak command produces error. `error: org.freefilesync.FreeFileSync/*unspecified*/*unspecified* not installed
`

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it!. Application was installed at `/opt/FreeFileSync`. I checked that folder and I found `unistall.sh`.